# Mariadb/MyISAM: Incompatible key or row definition between the MariaDB .frm file and the information in the storage engine. You have to dump an

Tags: mysql, mariadb, partitioning

We have a db with around 150 tables in, of which about 30 or so are partitioned as such :

```
ALTER TABLE `myTable`
  REORGANIZE PARTITION PFUTURE INTO (PARTITION P201910 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-11-01'),
             PARTITION PFUTURE VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE);
```

We've been automatically partitioning these tables on a monthly basis for around 3 years now without any issue.  Recently on 1 of the tables, after a partitioning exercise (with no errors/warnings reported) we see this :

> Got error 190 "Incompatible key or row definition between the MariaDB
>   .frm file and the information in the storage engine. You have to dump
>   an

from storage engine MyISAM" whilst running a `show table status`.  I have restored from a backup (after stopping/starting mariadb) and re-issued the command, and the same error is reported.

Repair table fails with the same message.

Is there a process I can follow to un-corrupt the table and make the partitioning process complete?

*We're using MariaDB 10.4.8.  We are not in a position to use any other table format, MyISAM is what we have and what we have to stick with for now.*

What I should mention is that we recently upgraded to MariaDB 10.4.8, and although I'd instantly jump on that as being the cause, the other 29 tables partitioned perfectly.

Comment: Try the `USE_FRM` option on `REPAIR TABLE`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I now get a warning: Can't open table, followed by an error 'Corrupt'.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

First check for all running queries and possible Connections your table might use. You can do this by

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

which gives you all running queries/Connections. You can terminate a query/Connection by

```
KILL <id>;
```

After that repair your table

```
REPAIR TABLE myTable;
```

Try to run this more than once until your Status Returns as `ok`. After that

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE myTable:
```

Then you can use the table again.

Comment: I think thats straight off one of the 1st hits in google :) Thanks for the info, but the repair fails (even repeatedly) as noted in the question.